# Why Jarque - Bera values are so high? Is this normal?

Tags: statistics, distribution, volatility-skew, kurtosis

Please advise whether the following is a normal occurrence:

[image]

In the above table I have Autocorrelation at lag1, LB, Skew, Kurt and JB test.

I have noticed that whenever the value of Kurt increases, the JB increases exponentially. In some cases I even have JB=106000.35

Am using Eviews 9.5 to calculate it.

Please advise on the results of the above (as I have to report these values in the table).

Much obliged
West

Comment: You can verify it yourself using the [formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jarque%E2%80%93Bera_test) but this doesn’t seem unreasonable. This is more of a statistic question than Quantitative Finance question si I will close.

Comment: I have verified it with the formula, thanks. To me it is quant finance as am using it to analyse hedge fund investments. PS. Should I simply ignore extremely high JB values in my description of the results?

Comment: It is evidence that the distribution is not Normal, the skewness and kurtosis are excessive compared to those of a Normal Distribution. Which is not too surprising for daily returns.